# "Migrate to Junit 5" option not availble in IntelliJ 2018.3.6 for groovy classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

If I have a java class running on JUnit4 e.g. "Mytest.java" it is possible to choose "Migrate to Junit5" from pulldown window menu in IntelliJ. But if I have a similar file called "Mytest2.groovy" this migration option is no longer available.

I can convert "Mytest2.groovy" manually to JUnit5 by rewriting the code. But I am dealing with thousands of groovy classes written in Junit4 that I wish to convert.

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MyTest {

```
@Test
public void testing() {
    assertEquals("Testing: ", 300, addition(27,300));
}

public int addition(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
}
```

}

Comment: There is no such action/inspection for Groovy code. Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Done! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224370c